# Flutter - Google maps crash on resize

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

In my use case, I need to make sure that my map can resize dynamically without crashing, you may suggest using resizeToAvoidBottomPadding, but my problem is beyond that, for example, my app crashes if I'm using facebook messanger chat head and open it's keyboard (which made the app resize forcing the map to resize hence the crash)

the following code is inside a sub-route (inside a route containing a bottom tab bar, so the following code is inside one of the bar's buttons)

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        GoogleMap(
          onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
          mapType: MapType.normal,
          initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
            target: LatLng(30, 40),
            zoom: 11,
          ),
          onCameraMove: (pos) {
            setState(() {
              // do something
            });
          },
          onCameraIdle: () {
            setState(() {
              // do something
            });
          },
        ),
        TextField(),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Edit: this is the error message I get in the console:

```
E/flutter (16068): [ERROR:flutter/shell/platform/android/platform_view_android_jni.cc(39)] java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "void io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformView.onInputConnectionLocked()"
E/flutter (16068):  at io.flutter.plugin.platform.VirtualDisplayController.onInputConnectionLocked(VirtualDisplayController.java:166)
E/flutter (16068):  at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformViewsController.lockInputConnection(PlatformViewsController.java:370)
E/flutter (16068):  at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformViewsController.access$1000(PlatformViewsController.java:36)
E/flutter (16068):  at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformViewsController$1.resizePlatformView(PlatformViewsController.java:165)
E/flutter (16068):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformViewsChannel$1.resize(PlatformViewsChannel.java:120)
E/flutter (16068):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformViewsChannel$1.onMethodCall(PlatformViewsChannel.java:57)
E/flutter (16068):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:222)
E/flutter (16068):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:96)
E/flutter (16068):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:656)
E/flutter (16068):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/flutter (16068):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
E/flutter (16068):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
E/flutter (16068):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
E/flutter (16068):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/flutter (16068):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
E/flutter (16068):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
E/flutter (16068):  at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:107)
E/flutter (16068): 
F/flutter (16068): [FATAL:flutter/shell/platform/android/platform_view_android_jni.cc(76)] Check failed: CheckException(env). 
F/libc    (16068): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 16068 (m.dm.dm_testing)
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/a7xeltexx/a7xelte:7.0/NRD90M/A710FXXU2CQG4:user/release-keys'
Revision: '3'
ABI: 'arm'
pid: 16068, tid: 16068, name: m.dm.dm_testing  >>> com.dm.dm_testing <<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
Abort message: '[FATAL:flutter/shell/platform/android/platform_view_android_jni.cc(76)] Check failed: CheckException(env). 
'
    r0 00000000  r1 00003ec4  r2 00000006  r3 00000008
    r4 ec60358c  r5 00000006  r6 ec603534  r7 0000010c
    r8 ffcc802c  r9 db59415c  sl 00000032  fp db594110
    ip 0000000b  sp ffcc7f08  lr ea8f04c7  pc ea8f2d30  cpsr 000e0010
backtrace:
    #00 pc 0004ad30  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
    #01 pc 000484c3  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+34)
    #02 pc 0001dd99  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
    #03 pc 00019521  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+34)
    #04 pc 00017160  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
    #05 pc 00fa7b9f  /data/app/com.dm.dm_testing-1/lib/arm/libflutter.so (offset 0xf99000)
    #06 pc 00f9dde1  /data/app/com.dm.dm_testing-1/lib/arm/libflutter.so (offset 0xf99000)
    #07 pc 00f9cad7  /data/app/com.dm.dm_testing-1/lib/arm/libflutter.so (offset 0xf99000)
    #08 pc 00fcfb83  /data/app/com.dm.dm_testing-1/lib/arm/libflutter.so (offset 0xf99000)
    #09 pc 00fa81f5  /data/app/com.dm.dm_testing-1/lib/arm/libflutter.so (offset 0xf99000)
    #10 pc 00fab943  /data/app/com.dm.dm_testing-1/lib/arm/libflutter.so (offset 0xf99000)
    #11 pc 00011e77  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper9pollInnerEi+614)
    #12 pc 00011b83  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper8pollOnceEiPiS1_PPv+26)
    #13 pc 00097325  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android18NativeMessageQueue8pollOnceEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjecti+22)
    #14 pc 7594bd55  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.oat (offset 0x38c0000)
Lost connection to device.
```

thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you mean the app closes with error? Provide error stacktrace

Comment: I edited the question adding the required info @Pavel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug [related to changes in Gradle 3.5.0](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40126#issuecomment-534209729). It's currently fixed in the Flutter master channel.

If you want to work around it now, add `android.enableDexingArtifactTransform=false` to your `gradle.properties` file to disable the new Gradle changes.

Comment: awesome, the workaround worked for me, do you recommend moving to the master channel ? I'm currently using gradle 5.4.1

Comment: It's [usually better to stay on stable](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Flutter-build-release-channels#which-channel-should-i-use). The workaround shouldn't cause any other blocking issues, so I think it's fine to just use that for now.

Answer (score 1):

1. Wrap your Stack with Expanded widget
2. Wrap Expanded Widget with Column

You are done...

Comment: Do you mean Expanded instead of Extended?